# How to fix not displaying exact value in getting midarray in java

Tags: java

I have a problem on displaying the exact value in getting the value of midarray in specific data input. I hope anybody can help me in my problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get number of numbers to include in our array from the user
    int arraySize = getInputInteger(scan, userPrompt, invalidMsg);

    // Get array input from the user
    int[] values = getInputArrayInts(scan, arraySize);
    int[] mid = midArray(values);

    // Print results
    System.out.println("Mid Range: " + mid);
}

public static int[] midArray(int[] arr) {
        int extra = arr.length % 2 == 0? 1 : 0;

        int[] mid = new int[1 + extra];

        int startIndex = arr.length / 2 - extra;
        int endIndex = arr.length / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i <= endIndex - startIndex; i++) {
            mid[i] = arr[startIndex + i];
        }
return mid;

}
```

Output data:

```
List of Inputs: [1,2,3,4,5]
Mid Range: [I@3bb2b8 // it display not exact value instead of displaying 3
```

Comment: Why are you returning an array instead of a single `int`?

Comment: Is it a mid value or a mid range of values you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print an array you have to iterate over all elements or you can use the method [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) of Arrays:

> Returns **a string representation of the contents of the specified array**. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(short). Returns "null" if a is null.

So you need to do something like that in the print statement:

```
 System.out.println("Mid Range: " + Arrays.toString(mid));
```

Comment: @UnusInstarOmnium if it works and You think it is the right answer you can upvote and flag it as correct.